# Union cannot be defined in a type specifier

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to include a c code library from Github in my C++ application but encountered some compile error.

Errors for the original code:

```
'_u16' cannot be defined in a type specifier


non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

The application is compiled by Clang 10.0.1 using CMake on macOS with following in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Following is the original code:

```
inline static void UInt16SetBE(void *b2, uint16_t u)
{
    *(union _u16 { uint8_t u8[16/8]; } *)b2 = (union _u16) { (u >> 8) & 0xff, u & 0xff };
}
```

Following is my code after adding casting to try to resolve the error:

```
inline static void UInt16SetBE(void *b2, uint16_t u)
{
    *(union _u16 { uint8_t u8[16/8]; } *)b2 = (union _u16) { (uint8_t)((u >> 8) & 0xff), (uint8_t)(u & 0xff) };
}
```

Errors after my change:

```
'_u16' cannot be defined in a type specifier
```

Does anyone know what the syntax of the declaration means?
`*(union _u16 { uint8_t u8[16/8]; } *)b2`

Comment: That's a cast. An awful, awful cast.

Comment: Might add some more awful.

Comment: That code could hardly be more [write-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language) if that was the developer's original goal.

Comment: It may be better to just compile the library you found with a C compiler as it was intended and use it as a library. C and C++ are distinct languages and what works in one may not work the same way in the other. Specially when it's manipulating bytes like this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Given that the function is `inline`, there is a good chance that it is defined in the header, so the OP won't be able to separately compile and link it with C++ translation units. That said, the fact that this library is not already valid C++ implies that the author made no effort to make it valid C++, so I agree that it may fail to work in other ways as well, and should ideally be avoided in a C++ program.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs! The inline function is indeed in the header. I will create a pull request to apply the fix to the Github library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are declaring a union type, `_u16`, which contains an array of two bytes, and then they pretend the pointer `b2` is a pointer to a union of that type. Then, they take `u` and take the upper and lower bytes of it, and have them assigned to the two positions of that array respectively. It is a rather messy way of setting a big-endian 16-bit value.

Your attempt to fix the compilation error was in the right direction, but for it to work with Clang I think you need to declare the union type first so the compiler recognizes it in the right-hand side of the assignment.

```
inline static void UInt16SetBE(void *b2, uint16_t u)
{
    union _u16 { uint8_t u8[16/8]; };
    *(union _u16 *)b2 = (union _u16) { (uint8_t)((u >> 8) & 0xff), (uint8_t)(u & 0xff) };
}
```

That said, that code is quite confusing, and there are simpler ways of doing the same, such as simply:

```
inline static void UInt16SetBE(void *b2, uint16_t u)
{
    ((uint8_t *) b2)[0] = (uint8_t) (u >> 8) & 0xff;
    ((uint8_t *) b2)[1] = (uint8_t) u & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I think that the OP was mostly confused about the inlined union type declaration, but the function definitely needs replacing. I am always wary of saying "this is equivalent to this simpler thing" in C++ because there is such a myriad of reasons why two things that should be equal are not _always_ equal, but I don't think any strange corner case of the original syntax would be desirable any way...

Answer (score 3):

In C, the expression

```
*(union _u16 { uint8_t u8[16/8]; } *)b2
```

defines a union with tag `_u16`, casts `b2` to a pointer to that newly-defined union type, then dereferences the pointer. However, in C++, attempting to define a class or union type inside a cast in this manner is invalid syntax. We can fix this by moving the definition ahead:

```
union _u16 { uint8_t u8[16/8]; };
*(union _u16*)b2 = (union _u16) { (u >> 8) & 0xff, u & 0xff };
```